# Android Studio how to run copy task?

Tags: javascript, android-studio, gradle, syntax, aar

I can't copy an aar file when I build the gradle:

```
task copyAAR(type: Copy){
    dependsOn assemble
    from ('build/outputs/aar')
    into ('../../out')
    include(project.name + '-release.aar')
}
```

ERROR:

```
10:56:46 PM: Executing task 'copyAAR'...

java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
10:56:46 PM: Task execution finished 'copyAAR'.
```

After i searched several forums I decided to ask question, I don't know how to fix this could someone help me?

I followed this video, starts at 4:20 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmNMugkOQBI&t=313s

Answer (score 0):

I solved it,
the syntax was ok. The problem was in the Edit Configuration.. When I added the gradle I put a wrong path but it's unnecessary to do that. After you write the code for the task a green arrow will appear:

[image]

Click that and Android Studio will add your gradle automatically:

[image]

That's it, I'm still noob at Android Studio!